# Multiple barh subplots automatically from loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to create multiple bar charts automatically in a loop using a subplot.

I have created a function to create the parameters for the plot according to how many plots I need like so:

```
def create_parameters(parameters):
exec("def f_create_parameters({}): pass".format(', '.join(parameters)))
return locals()['f_create_parameters']
```

and the code that uses the function:

```
    parList = []
    names = []
    even = 2
    odd = 1
    for i in range (0, len(listOfCategoriesEN)*2):
       parList.append(create_parameters(["ax"+str(odd),"ax"+str(even)]))
       names.append("ax"+str(odd))
       names.append("ax"+str(even))
       odd+=2
      even+=2
```

Then this is the code where I am trying to create a single figure with multiple plots. I am getting all the plots overlayed on the last bar graph. Any idea how to fix it:

```
 val = 0

fig2, (parList) = plt.subplots(len(listOfCategoriesEN)*2,2,figsize=(20,20)) 
for name,dict_ in categoriesDict.items():
    df =  pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_, orient='index', columns=["Title", "Pageviews"])
    df = df.sort_values(by=['Pageviews'], ascending=False)
    df[ "Pageviews"] = df[ "Pageviews"].astype(int)
    #get top 5
    df1 = df.head(5)
    df1 = df1.sort_values(by=['Pageviews'], ascending=True)
    df1['Title'] = df1['Title'].str.replace('&#8217;','\'')



if(not df1.empty):
    
    x = df1['Title']
    y = df1['Pageviews']
    locals()[names[val]].barh(x, y, color=colours)
    #locals()[names[val]].set_title(name+" TOP 5 PAGES")
    val+=1
```

plt.show()

Answer (score 0):

`parList` is a list of all your subplots.
By using plt.sca(ax) (sca = set current axis) you select the active axis to be `ax` and then plot your data:

```
val = 0
for name,dict_ in categoriesDict.items():
    # do your data stuff

    if(not df1.empty):
    
        x = df1['Title']
        y = df1['Pageviews']
        ax = parList[val//2, val%2] # needs to be changed if you rearrange your plots
        plt.sca(ax)
        locals()[names[val]].barh(x, y, color=colours)
        #locals()[names[val]].set_title(name+" TOP 5 PAGES")
        val+=1
```